# NSManagedObjectContext autorelease Issue

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nszombie

I have been battling this for a long time now. My understanding of Autorelease is that when it doesnt need it any longer it will release it.

I was getting one of those evil EXC_BAD_ACCESS without any details.
It would just crash on:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     @autoreleasepool {
         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Logix_AppDelegate      class]));
     }
 }
```

With Zombies enabled I found that I was writing to CoreData in a loop
here is my initialization of the NSManagedObjectContext

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] autorelease];
```

Any thoughts here.... there is a lot of code, so I didnt want to paste volumes of stuff here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autorelease` adds an object to the current autorelease pool. That object will receive a `release` message (and potentially be deallocated) when the current autorelease pool is destroyed.

Sending `autorelease` to an object makes sense only if you *own* that object. In your case, the `managedObjectContext` method has not "new", "alloc" or "copy" in its name, so you don't own the returned object and must not call `autorelease` on it.

So you should replace that line by

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

See also [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide":

> **You own any object you create**
>   You create an object using a method
>   whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for
>   example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy). ...
>
> **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
>   You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a `release`
>   message or an `autorelease` message. ...
>
> **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**

Comment: I think I may have gotten that piece of code for coredata from an online source... guess that is not the best place to get code. I did it the way you said, but it caused some more errors. I will have to dig deeper. This is a good start. That was the best explanation of autorelease anyone has provided!

Comment: @logixologist: Do you have the option to migrate your project to ARC (automatic reference counting)? The ARC compiler is very clever and makes most retain/release problems just vanish. (But it still helps to know what is happening "behind the scenes".)

Comment: I thought about it seriously but its too close to being completed doing it manually, I didnt want to risk having to fix a lot of errors. Have you done a ARC Conversion and how much work was it to fix after the fact.

Comment: Ok working fine now. Thanks! I guess I had my memory management a little off. I had gotten rid of the context and that was causing it to give me the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.